# httpresponseredirect not working

Tags: django, redirect

for sign up page,

I have a view setup like the following

```
def signup(request):
  if request.method == 'GET':
      return render_to_response(..)
  elif request.method == 'POST':
      ...
      return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user_home', args=[user_id])

[10/Jan/2013 16:11:53] "GET /site/signup/ HTTP/1.1" 200 62097
[10/Jan/2013 16:12:20] "POST /site/signup/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[10/Jan/2013 16:12:20] "GET /gallery/user/19 HTTP/1.1" 200 31575
```

Even though server log shows `GET /gallery/user/19`, I still see the submit form page on my browser.
Why the redirecting isn't working for me?

Comment: Generally, I have this problem with Ajax request. Try clearing you cache

Comment: Is the submit form in the if or the elif condition?

Comment: @bozdoz: submit form is shown in 'GET'.

Comment: @Raunak: I cleared and disabled cache. still same.

Comment: Do you have login required with a redirect back to the submit form page? If so maybe you are not authenticating the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what this does, but commenting out did the job
What does it do?

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
// {% include 'include/jquery.ajaxupload.js'%}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

// $('document').ready(function(){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
//      var $form = $('#form-signupForm form');                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

//      $form.submit(function(){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
//              $(this).ajaxSubmit({                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
//                      success:function(response){                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
//                              console.log(response);                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
//                      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
//              });                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
//              return false;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
//      });                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     



});                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
</script>
```